# trying to close Vim in Cygwin

Tags: yaml, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin64 on Win 10, and when I open vim in Cygwin64, it works and I can close it too. But When I add a certificate, I can't close it.

```sh
~/rbac$ vim signing-request.yaml
```

```yaml
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: student-csr
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: <assign encoded value from next cat command>
  signerName: kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - client auth
```

I tired the following options to close it:

```
:q
:x
:wq
:q!
```

None of these works after I add the certificate.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how you added the certificate ?

Comment: I just past it directly

Comment: vim has no certificate functionality, as I can see on the documentation. So be a more precise and clarify: what type of certificate, what type of functionality are you trying to use. May be you are trying to manage certificate for something like https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/ ?